# Callback happen after i close the program

Tags: c#, wpf, websocket, socket.io

I`m developing wpf client-server app. Now i communicate with the server via Web Socket protocol by using SocketIOClient library. Now I declare on the `On events` like that:

```
 private void DeclareGetDataEvents()
        {
            _socket.On("UpdateRivalPoints", (data) =>
            {
                RivalPoints++;
            });
            _socket.On("WinGame", (data) =>
            {
                this.IsUserWin = true;
            });
            _socket.On("OnlineFreeUsers", (users) =>
            {
                UsersNames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<string>>($"[{users.ToString().Trim(new Char[] {'[', ']', '\\'})}]");
            });
            _socket.On("WantedPlay", (rivalName) =>
            {
                IsRequestReceived = true;
                RivalName = rivalName.ToString().Trim(new Char[] { '[', ']', '\"' });
                PlayRequestString = $"{RivalName} want to play!";
            });
            _socket.On("StartPlay", (data) =>
            {
                IsGameOnline = true;
                RivalPoints = 0;
                IsUserWin = false;
                App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    var window = new GameView();
                    window.ShowDialog();
                });
            });
            _socket.On("RefusedPlay", (data) =>
            {
                PlayRequestString = $"{RivalName} refused to play against you";
            });
        }
```

Now the problem is that the callback inside the `UpdateRivalPoints evnet` and inside `WinGame event` happens only after i close the program and not immediately when the event arrived.

I tried to make the callback with `BeginInvoke` like that:

```
_socket.On("UpdateRivalPoints", async(data) => await App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send,new                                         
          UpdateRivalPointsDelegate(UpdateRivalPointsMethod)));
```

But it still doesnt work.
The `On` function requires the following as arguments: `string eventName` and `Action<SocketIORespone callback`

Comment: Is the program busy doing something on the ui thread?

Comment: Yes, this 2 events should happen while the game window is shown,  and there is several threads that runs at the same time, so  i belive that the program is busy.
But i also tried to delete the all the threads so that the program not busy on the ui thread and get the events and it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue here is that the UI is not updated immediately after the event arrives (this can only be done on the UI thread), so what you need to do is to wrap all the updates to the UI elements in App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke, to ensure that the updates are made on the UI thread.

Something like this:

```
_socket.On("UpdateRivalPoints", (data) =>
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        RivalPoints++;
    });
});
```

For all of the UI updates.

Comment: I did the same like you wrote and it still doesn’t work. It’s going into the callback only after I close the program